# Easiest Way To Do All-To-All Union Of Postgres Database Tables?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, duplicates, union, distributed-caching

Consider the situation where N machines have one postgres database each, having a table A of the same schema and meaning. I really need to stick to this architecture for performance reasons, but refreshing each database with the union of all their collective data is kind of a pain.

The extent I've been able to automate this is a shell script doing:

```
mycopy=tableA_`hostname`.pg
pg_dump -t tableA -d $database | sed "s/tableA/$mycopy" > $mycopy
for host in host_x host_y host_z; do
   scp $mycopy host:~/
done
```

And then the sql script:

```
BEGIN;
\i tableA_hostx.pg
\i tableA_hosty.pg
\i tableA_hostz.pg
CREATE TABLE new_tableA AS
               (select * from tableA)
UNION DISTINCT (select * from tableA_hostx)
UNION DISTINCT (select * from tableA_hosty)
UNION DISTINCT (select * from tableA_hostz);
DROP TABLE tableA;
DROP TABLE table_hostx;
DROP TABLE table_hosty;
DROP TABLE table_hostz;
ALTER TABLE new_tableA rename to tableA;
COMMIT;
```

But this is a very well-defined and ordinary thing I feel I am doing, so I wonder if there is some advanced higher-level interface for such all-to-all communication. There are some distributed database approaches described in [the postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling), but can any of them do exactly this and otherwise not force me to rethink or redesign much about my database?

Comment: why you dont use [**replication**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-on-postgresql-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) ??

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I would need to run pg_basebackup (N-1) times on each of the N hosts, right? I'm not sure what benefits that has over the pg_dump+scp approach. Will it automatically merge each of the tables with a UNION DISTINCT, like I'm doing in my sql script? Also, I don't want to be merging my other tables, just table A.

Comment: What postgresql version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use foreign tables for that.

For each remote host create one foreign table. Then create a materialized view that contains the `union` query.

When you want to refresh everything, all you need to do is `refresh materialized view tablea_combined`. No dumping or restoring required.

Of course that assumes that the server where you combine all that can connect to all other servers.

If you just want a convenient way to select all those tables, a simple view might be enough - it depends on what you do with that if the performance is good enough.

If you use 9.5 or later you can create a partitioned table that [uses inheritance](https://www.depesz.com/2015/04/02/waiting-for-9-5-allow-foreign-tables-to-participate-in-inheritance/) combining the foreign tables into one table on your "master" server. To make that efficient, this requires that you have a column that identifies the "source" server and can thus be used as a partitioning key.

Answer (score 1):

[What @a_horse said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40537837/939860): Use a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) on [foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html).

Plus, use a simpler query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW new_tableA AS 
      TABLE tableA
UNION TABLE tableA_hostx  -- being a foreign table
UNION TABLE tableA_hosty
UNION TABLE tableA_hostz;
```

- `UNION` returns distinct rows anyway, no need for a redundant `DISTINCT`. (You would use `UNION ALL` keep duplicates.)
- [`TABLE tableA`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) is an SQL shorthand for `SELECT * FROM tableA`.